# Trouble installing colorama

Tags: python, pip, colorama

```
C:\Users\*****>pip install colorama
Collecting colorama
  Using cached colorama-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Installing collected packages: colorama
Successfully installed colorama-0.4.3

C:\Users\*****>python
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import colorama
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colorama'
>>> exit()

C:\Users\*****>pip uninstall colorama
Found existing installation: colorama 0.4.3
Uninstalling colorama-0.4.3:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\rober\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\colorama-0.4.3.dist-info\*
    c:\users\rober\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\colorama\*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled colorama-0.4.3

C:\Users\*****>pip install "C:\Users\rober\Downloads\colorama-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl"
Processing c:\users\rober\downloads\colorama-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: colorama
Successfully installed colorama-0.4.3

C:\Users\*****>python
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import colorama
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colorama'
```

I don't know what to do. You can see where I've downloaded the file, I'm running the latest pip version and python 3.8. After searching the internet I've come back empty handed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you still need help for this but I had the same problem and managed to solve it.

I just went into cmd and put:

```
pip install colorama --user
```

and it worked for me (new to coding and python so I've got 3.8.3 and have had similar issues with several pip installs).

Answer (score -1):

From the traces

launching `python` runs the 64 bit of python

```
C:\Users\*****>python
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

now when you uninstall:

```
C:\Users\*****>pip uninstall colorama
Found existing installation: colorama 0.4.3
Uninstalling colorama-0.4.3:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\rober\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\colorama-0.4.3.dist-info\*
    c:\users\rober\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\colorama\*
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled colorama-0.4.3
```

it uninstalls unto the 32 bit version (note the `-32` suffix).

So `pip` probably points to the 32 bit version.

What would work would be using the python command and the `-m` option to make sure that the proper install is used to install modules:

```
python -m pip install colorama
```

You can use `where pip` and `where python`, that will confirm that those point to different python packages.

If you don't use it, I suggest that you uninstall the 32-bit version of python to avoid further mixups.